# Whats the difference between a TastyPie Resource and Django view that returns a JSON object?

Tags: django, tastypie

Why would I want to use TastyPie when I could just return JSON from a Django view?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Returning JSON is just the tip of it.

Some things you otherwise have to do yourself if you're not using tastypie:

- Filtering/Search
- Sorting
- Easy construction of the JSON response
- Authentication / Authorization
- Caching
- Throttling
- Serialization

Resource: http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/toc.html

Answer (score 2):

It's funny I watched a djangocon presentation on TastyPie just yesterday, here:
http://blip.tv/djangocon/building-apis-in-django-with-tastypie-5572790

At 5:44 the speaker answers your question exactly as you put it, please take a look!

I guess the answer is: sure you can use JSON, it's just that TastyPie will take care of response headers, enable choosing serialization formats etc, things that would facilitate restful APIs. With a couple of views it would be simple to implement custom behavior but when designing a complicated system automating the process with TastyPie could save time. Why do work that already has been done anyway? Please check out the presentation if you're not bored of webinars, I believe it's interesting!